# How do I add php if statement into my form

Tags: php, mysql

I have an update form where users can update their information, but some of the information should not be able to be updated if it already has a value.

From what I understand you must put php code outside the form tags so how would the form know if the database field has a value or not? Would this work below im guessing it won't

```
<form>
<?php    
if (empty($user_data['fieldName'])) {
      echo '<label>field name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fieldName">';
      }
?>
</form>
```

Does anyone know a way around this? Or how would i check before the field is displayed in the update area?

Comment: You can put php code anywhere. As long as it is enclosed the opening/closing tags !!

Comment: if you want it to be unchangeable you should limit it like that on the server side. It's the safest way. Afterwards you can simply make the form display a disabled field.

Comment: Simple tutorial http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/ Do some reading so you have a basic idea of how to code a web page and incorporate PHP scripts with it.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code is correct, you may have a problem when assigning the user data in the array $user_data.

An alternative would be to simply disable the input text, that way you could display information to the user without letting him change it.

```
 <form>
    <?php 
       $disabled = "";
       if (empty($user_data['fieldName'])) {
           $disabled = 'disabled="disabled"'
       } ?>
           <label>field name</label>
           <input type="text" name="fieldName" <?php echo $disabled; ?>/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do in that way but you should check on the server too if not update exist

Also the most readable way of do this is using alternate php syntax like this

```
<form>
  <?php if (empty($user_data['fieldName'])): ?>
      <label>field name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fieldName">
  <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

in that way you can see colors of your html code

see this link, 
[Alternative php syntax](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/alternative_php.html)
the doc is for codeigniter but is applicable on clean php

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you can put PHP anywhere in a `*.php` file, so long as it is enclosed in the correct opening and closing tags.

That said, this is a two-sided process:

In the form I would suggest simply disabling the input, so the data is shown, but is not modifiable:

```
<form>
<label>field name</label>
      <input type="text" value="<?php echo addslashes($user_data['fieldName']) ?>" name="fieldName" <?php if(!empty($user_data['fieldName'])) { echo 'disabled="disabled"; } ?> />
</form>
<?php /* Off the top of my head I can not remember how exactly to escape this
form value, it may be `htmlspecialchars`, but it eludes me in the immediate
moment.  Sorry. */ ?>
```

And on your server-side, where you handle the form post data, you will want to double-check that someone didn't forge the data:

```
if(!empty($user_data['fieldName']) && !empty($_POST['fieldName'])) {
  unset($_POST['fieldName']);
}
```

This way you avoid people modifying the form structure on the client to forge data into your system.  You should always do similar checks.

Comment: I am not sure I would agree with this for an answer that meets the OPs question. Sometimes it IS desirable to not include a form field, for example if you're writing two views for the same form: one for admins and one for users. I would rather they not even SEE the admin user data.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a presentation code, like this :

```
<form>
    <label>field name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fieldName" <?=!empty($user_data['fieldName'])?'disabled="disabled"':''?>>
</form>
```

And a script to update, where you must check if value is set before updating.